# z-index causes div to cover everything even when div is transformed off screen

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, z-index

I have a slide in menu, it slides in because I use `useState` to set the state of a boolean variable, and if that variable is true, the div is not set to transform, but if it's false I transform the x by 100%.

```
    menu: {
        transform: open ? 'translateX(0)' : 'translateX(-100%)',
        overflowY: 'scroll',
        transition: 'transform 0.3s ease-in-out'
    },
```

This gif shows the functionality. If my slide in div is positioned below the filter button, then I can click the filter button, but if the slide in div is positioned to the top of the screen, then the filter button is covered, and it does not work. I know that I can conditionally set the `z-index` of the container(parent of `sideMenu`) but then there is no animation when closing the side menu.

[image]

I would like the buttons to be able to work when the slide in menu is positioned off screen.

Comment: Please post all the relevant code (HTML as well).

Comment: You need to make sure that at the end of the animation you `display: none` your slide in  panel, it is possible you are only sliding it away and due to z-index you can still interact with it